# How to order multiple values in a field collection

Tags: nodes, entities

I have an Content type which includes a field of type Field collection, of which there can be an unlimited number of values. I can't work out how to order the rows of data that are displayed by this field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can order the Items when you are creating it using the widget that is next to the field. I mean this (It is a field collection that contains multiple fields)

[image]

and if you need to sort the items after adding the content, you can use  [Field Collection views](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection_views) module. This module creates a view of type field collection and by some configurations you can get what you want.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like Field Collection Views is what I need.

Comment: You welcome, If you think it is the correct solution for your question Please check as accepted for people who visit your question in the future